# Remove duplicates on a loop in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I am getting an error on a classic asp page (error '80020009')

The simplified and cleaned code is the following

```
  Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

  rs.Fields.Append "eventnum", 3

  rs.Open
  rs.AddNew "eventnum", "26856"
  rs.AddNew "eventnum", "26857"
  rs.AddNew "eventnum", "26857"
  rs.Update


  rs.movefirst
  while not rs.eof

    holdereventnum = rs("eventnum")
    response.write rs("eventnum") & "<br>"

    rs.movenext

    if not rs.eof then
       while holdereventnum=rs("eventnum") and not rs.eof
           rs.movenext
       wend
    end if

   wend
```

So if the recordset returns 

23856

26857

26857

it fails, but if returns

26857

26857

23856

it works, and I can't figure it out why.

The error is reported on the following line:

```
while holdereventnum=rs("eventnum") and not rs.eof
```

Any clue is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

i assume the error you're getting isn't related to the following line missing the THEN keyword and it was just a typo:

```
if not rs.eof
```

instead of trying to remove the duplicates in your asp code, can you update your sql to not select any duplicates by using the DISTINCT keyword in your sql?

```
select distinct( eventNum ) from table where....
```

The error itself is saying that there is no record to be read from, that it's indeed EOF, even with the IF statement check there. I've never had much luck trying to get a loop within a loop using the same recordset to work. If you're unable to modify your sql, convert your RS to an array using GetRows, then loop through the array from within your WHILE loop

Answer (score 0):

The solution was related to change the way how the loop was used.

```
Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Fields.Append "eventnum", 3

rs.Open
rs.AddNew "eventnum", "26856"
rs.AddNew "eventnum", "26857"
rs.AddNew "eventnum", "26857"
rs.Update


rs.movefirst
while not rs.eof

  holdereventnum = rs("eventnum")
  response.write rs("eventnum") & "<br>"

  rs.movenext

  if not rs.eof then
    do while holdereventnum=rs("eventnum") and not rs.eof
       rs.movenext
       if rs.eof then exit do end if
    loop
  end if

wend
```